# Strange Zend_Session behaviour using Zend_Application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session, zend-application, zend-app-bootstrap

I'm writing to see if someone of you guys has encountered this problem before and have a chance to understand why it happened to me.

This is the story.

I developed many ZF applications before Zend Framework v. 1.8, then I've stopped for about 18 months. Now I had to start a new project on which I decided to use Zend Framework again.

On my local server I had the version 1.11.3 installed, so I didn't download the latest release.

Before the use of Zend_Application with the Bootstrap.php file I used to start sessions putting my session options in my config.ini file and then loading them into a Zend_Session instance like this:

config.ini

```
sessions.name = NAME
sessions.use_only_cookies = 1
sessions.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp/sessions"
sessions.strict = on
sessions.remember_me_seconds = 1800
```

index.php (into the public webserver directory) before starting the application:

```
Globals::startSession();
```

custom Globals class with various useful methods:

```
    class Globals
    {
            static public function startSession()
            {
            $sessions_conf = self::getConfig()->sessions;
            Zend_Session::setOptions($sessions_conf->toArray(););
            Zend_Session::start();
            }
    }
```

This has always worked very well, enabling my sessions (used with Zend_Session_Namespace) and storing the session files in the save_path.

With Zend_Application the manual tells to simply store the session options in the application.ini file under the "section" resources and Zend_Session will be configured automatically...

I did it like this:

```
; SESSIONS
resources.session.name = NAME
resources.session.use_only_cookies = 1
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp/sessions"
resources.session.strict = on
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 1800
```

It didn't worked.
So I tried to use (not at the same time!) the _initSession() and _initForceSession() methods in the Bootstrap.php file, putting them at the beginning of the class and writing into them the code:

```
$this->bootstrap('session');
```

But session were never working, data were not stored between http requests and session files were never written into the save_path...

Could anyone, please, let me know if this is a normal behaviour (maybe I have missed something somewhere...)?

Obviously I solved the problem re-implementing my older method (and it works perfectly), but I would like to learn how to use it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post the code for your _initSession() and _initForceSession() (if different)?

Comment: No, the code is the same, there is only a call to Zend_Session::start();

Answer (score 1):

This should be a case of turn it on and it works, might have made it to easy.

I think you may have a problem with how you set your options in your application.ini:

```
; SESSIONS
resources.session.name = NAME
resources.session.name.use_only_cookies = 1
resources.session.name.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp/sessions"
resources.session.name.strict = on
resources.session.name.remember_me_seconds = 1800
```

according to the [reference manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.configuration_options)

> To set a session configuration option, include the basename (the part
>   of the name after "session.") as a key of an array passed to
>   Zend_Session::setOptions().

with your options set correctly the bootstrap _initSession() should just work.

```
public function _initSession()
{
Zend_Session::start();
}
```

P.S. I use Zend_Session_Namespace all the time but rarely deal with a global session.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I'll get a try tomorrow and let you know if I will be able to make it work correctly.

Comment: Nothing to do, I tried to use a basename after the session. part in my application.ini and set the _initSession() function in my Bootstrap.php, but, as before, no session file is stored in the save_path... I really can't understand why.

Comment: I did a test now using var_dump(Zend_Session::getOptions()); in my _initSession() in the Bootstrap.php file and it seems that none of my ini options have been set...

Comment: I've tried to insert the following in the __initSession() bootstrap function:

Comment: `code` public function _initSession()
 {
  //$this->bootstrap('session');
  //Globals::startSession();
  $options = Globals::getConfig()->resources->session;
  Zend_Session::setOptions($options->toArray());
  //var_dump(Zend_Session::getOptions());
  //exit();
  Zend_Session::start();
 }`code`
options are assigned to Zend_Session, but no result... always no files in the save_path. It's really strange, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

In your Bootstrap.php add

```
public function _initSession()
{
Zend_Session::start();
}
```

session options can be set in application.ini

Comment: I did use _initSession() as you suggested me, but without results, I think that something is missing, maybe the user RockyFord is right with his suggestions, I'll try tomorrow to implement them.

Comment: This solution gives me the same result of RockyFord's one, no session files are stored in the specified save_path...